# Очень, очень странно работает iframe

Tags: javascript, html

В чём суть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нажимаем на розовое троеточие

```
   <?php
include_once '../scripts/php/conf.php';
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>News</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../scripts/css/news.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../scripts/css/stylesheet.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../scripts/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                font-family: 'pixel';
            } 

            .scroll-pane {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 30%;
                width: 70%; 
                height: 100%; 
                overflow: auto;
                background-color: #828898;
            }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function openBand(URL) {
                var content = window.top.document.getElementById('content');
                content.src = URL;
                content.style.display = 'block';
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            $q = "SELECT * FROM `bands` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5";
            $result = mysql_query($q);

            echo '<div class="scroll-pane">';

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $block = '  
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="../bands/'.$row['band'].'/logo.jpg">
                    <div></div><p>'.$row['band'].'</p>
                    <span>Added a new album, just click to see the blades</span><br>
                    <a href="#" onClick="openBand(\'http://localhost/NetFM/bands/'.$row['band'].'/'.$row['band'].'.php\')">...</a>
                </div>';

                echo $block;
            }

            echo '
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function() {
                    jQuery(\'.scroll-pane\').jScrollPane();
                });
            </script>';

        ?>


    </body>

</html>
```

происходит загрузка страницы в iframe (name="content")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и случается Это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

исчезает вся верхняя строка исчезает

как???

Comment: никаких ф-ий использующих верхнюю строкцу просто нет

как и почему??

Comment: Нужно взглянуть на примере. так - может быть что угодно.... А еще зачем вы экранируете одинарную кавычку перед http и после php? Возможно это всё и ломает

Comment: исправил, там вроде этого

Comment: Когда я про пример говорил, я имел в виду скорее саму страницу посмотреть где этот код. Потому, что по коду тут все равно мало что сказать можно будет мне кажется.

Comment: исправил, любуйтесь

Answer (score 1):

Исправляется

```
position: fixed;
```

для `iframe`